# Erro 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, mysql, visual-studio-2017

Criei uma aplicação no visual studio 2017, formatei o pc e instalei a versao 2019 e desde então nenhuma aplicação que eu tente conectar ao banco de dados funciona.

sempre aparece esse erro:

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: A chave fornecida não estava presente no dicionário.
```

sempre da erro neste trecho:

```
   string cnx = "server=localhost;user=root;password=;database=ERP;";
   try
   {
        MySqlConnection conexao = new MySqlConnection(cnx);
        conexao.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("oi eu estou aberto");
    }
    catch(Exception erro)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(erro.Message);
    }
```

Tentei também usar no visual studio 2015 e nada..

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido, estava usando o xampp nao sei o que pode ter dado errado com ele ja que nunca tive problemas.

troquei para o wamp e voltou a funcionar